# can the caller function close the xml reader resource

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following function which takes url path and gets the reader. As i cannot close the reader and return it. Can the caller close the returned reader object.

```
public  XmlReader GetXMLContent(string Path)
        {
         XmlTextReader responseReader= new XmlTextReader(XmlUrlPath);                                                                                              
         return responseReader;
        }

 XmlTextReader myReader =  GetXMLContent("http://sample.xml");
 while() // loop through all the elements 
 {
 }

 myReader.close(); // close the reader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. When the method returns, the caller has effectively taken ownership of the reader (in this particular case).

Admittedly I'd use a `using` statement instead though:

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = GetXmlContent("http://sample.xml"))
{
    ...
}
```

... with your current proposed code, you won't close the reader if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @jon i am adding reader to cache , i execute about code only if caching is null , so if is use using reader is closing the object

Comment: @jon did i explain it clear?? i basically cache the sample.xml by using some key , i don't want to load everytime as it is a static file

Comment: jon i saw your code properly , the method call itself is in using ,kool got it thanks

Comment: @gov: Ah, you didn't mention the cache before. I would suggest that you *don't* cache disposable types such as `XmlTextReader`. Why not just read the whole document and cache it as an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`? Caching an `XmlReader` is pretty pointless - either you end up having to "rewind" it (if that's even possible) or reading from wherever the previous caller had left it, neither of which is appealing.

Comment: @jon , if you don't mind can you explain why we shouldn't cache xmlTextReader object , can you also suggest some good approach. Basically i have to write one function which can get xml file return a reader or so , i cannot keep making calls all the time as all the xml files are static,can you suggest good solution please

Comment: @gov: I've already suggested a different approach: read the data and cache that, instead of caching the reader. I've also already explained why it's not a good idea to cache an `XmlReader`. Please read my previous comment carefully.

Comment: @jon got it , thats great idea, i will change the code to xmldocument and cache the xml document , once again thanks for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `XmlTextReader` constructor. You should use the facrory method in `XmlReader`. [As described in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0
>   release, the recommended practice is
>   to create XmlReader instances using
>   the XmlReader.Create method. This
>   allows you to take full advantage of
>   the new features introduced in this
>   release.

Unless your method was simplified for this post, this would also make you method obsolete.

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("http://sample.xml"))
{
   // read
}
```

In case you need that method, you'd do it this way:

```
public XmlReader GetXMLContent(string path)
{
    XmlReader responseReader = XmlReader.Create(path);   
    // do something special
    return responseReader;
}

using(XmlReader r = this.GetXMLContent("http://sample.xml"))
{
    // read
}
```

Comment: i was using but i have to execute above code only if cache is null , if cache is present i will pull xmlreader from the cache , if i place the code inside that i cannot rturn the reader object as using is desposing the object

Comment: As Jon said already, you really should think about your approach of caching disposable objects. It can get you into a lot of trouble. Why do need to cache them?